# Is there a way to call the cursor from FormLabel when using RN Elements?

Tags: react-native-elements

I'm trying to see if there's a way to set focus when touching the part set by FormLabel.

Right now focus is set when a user touches the FormInput part. To make UX better I'd like to also call the cursor anytime a user touches the title of the input field.